# Is appending to lists in Standard ML O(n) time?

Tags: data-structures, sml, ml

I'm trying to insert elements at the end of a list, but I'm wondering if that would be slow?

I know that to append elements in Scheme requires traversing the entire list and thus O(N) time for a list of length N. Is that also true in ML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is true in all implementations of ML that I am aware of, though I certainly would believe that it's possible to create an implementation for which that is not the case.

Comment: Unless ML's pattern matching is vastly more flexible than Haskell's (which I find hard to believe, but cannot rule out) any such change would require a different API, in particular it would break all pattern matching on node lists.